# Advanced Custom Fields - category image

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get an image for I previously assigned to a category using `ACF`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$category_image = get_field('category_name', $category->term_id);
```

But it's not displaying the image.

Comment: I think this will display the object of the selected category .. can u please print the $category_image variable.

Comment: What is the value of `var_dump($category_image)` ?

Comment: it's printing bool(false)

Comment: yes, i was print the $category_image variable but it was print nothing

Answer (score 0):

use `get_option( 'taxonomy_image_' . $category->cat_ID);`

or the full code

```
<img src="<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
$term_id = $category->cat_ID; 
$image = get_option( 'taxonomy_image_' . $term_id ); 
echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php $category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [{$category->taxonomy}_{$category->term_id}](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/) format for the second parameter of the "get_field" function.

In your case it should be:

```
$category_image = get_field('category_name', 'category_' . $category->term_id);
```